# willRotateToInterfaceOrientation not getting called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, accelerometer

I have an issue when playing video while using the c "willRotateToInterfaceOrientation" function. Initially, I have my main view set on the landscape mode. The video is playing but then I tried to rotate it to portrait mode my project doesn't call the "willRotateToInterfaceOrientation" but when I tried to rotate it back to the landscapeleft mode and then rotate back again to the portrait mode   it's just the time the "willRotateToInterfaceOrientation" is called. can anyone please help me? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead of implementing code in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
        NSNotificationCenter* notifCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [notificationCenter addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(orientationChanged)
                   name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                 object:nil];

Add the following method
-(void) orientationChanged
{
         //Copy code from your willRotateToInterfaceOrientation method here.
}
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion it works just what I wanted but another problem occur my main view is the only thing that's rotating the subview which is my movieplayercontroller view is not rotating. thanks

Comment: @Jahn: Either You have to set the transform property of the movieplayer or implement [movieController.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but still there was no success of rotating my movieplayer view. but thanks for the suggestions.